# Where is cocoa-sharp in Mono

Tags: macos, mono

I downloaded and installed Mono 2.4.2.3 Framework for the Mac OS.  The docs say that the download includes the Cocoa Sharp framework binary.  But I don't see it anywhere.

Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reference to xanadont's answer, the -pkg gmcs compiler argument uses pkgconfig too, so the linked "explanation" in MonoDevelop's FAQ is not valid for this example.

If Cocoa# isn't showing up in the MonoDevelop references list, it's likely that the Mono libraries are not in the paths that pkg-config searches. This is likely because you have MacPorts (or maybe Fink) installed, which overrides the default pkg-config with its own.

You can check that pkg-config can resolve cocoa-sharp with the following command:

```
pkg-config --modversion cocoa-sharp
```

and verify the location of pkg-config with

```
which pkg-config
```

It should be in /usr/bin.

If this is indeed the problem, the fix is either to remove MacPorts from your PATH, or add Mono to your environment's PKG_CONFIG_PATH:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

Comment: I tried to run pkg-config, but it tells me command not found.

Comment: I checker further and apparently Mono installs a copy of pkg-config, ao I suggest you try reinstalling Mono.

Answer (score 3):

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/cocoa-sharp/

But you shouldn't really need to know *where* it is because during compilation all you need is the -pkg:cocoa-sharp option.  See this [tutorial](http://cocoa-sharp.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2&Itemid=4).

Edit:
To reference it from within MonoDevelop just use the ".Net Assembly" tab in the "Edit References" window and navigate to the above path.  Also, see [this explanation](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#I_added_an_assembly_to_the_GAC.2c_why_doesn%27t_it_appear_in_the_assemblies_list_when_I_try_to_add_a_reference_in_a_MonoDevelop_project.3f) as to why cocoa-sharp doesn't appear in the "Packages" tab.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to this and I thought cocoa-sharp would appear in the list of available references in MonoDevelop, but it does not.