# Mono + OS X: "No package 'cocoa-sharp' found"

Tags: c#, macos, mono

I have recently installed Mono and MonoDevelop on Mac OS X, and now I am trying to create a native C# app for Mac.  I tried following the [Mono tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications) to create this double-clickable "app", but got stuck.  My specific error was "no package 'cocoa-sharp' found" when I tried implementing the commands outlined in the documentation.

I searched SO and found others who were reporting missing the 'cocoa-sharp' package.  The [advice given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272507/where-is-cocoa-sharp-in-mono) in a thread over 3 years ago was to reinstall Mono.  What happens when that does not work?  Can I go get 'cocoa-sharp.pc' or whatever the specific file is and throw it into a particular directory manually?  Am I even going down the right path?

The command I used:

```
gmcs test.cs -pkg:cocoa-sharp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocoa-sharp is obsolete and the tutorial is outdated, but thankfully there is a good replacement: [MonoMac](https://github.com/mono/monomac/). You can fetch and compile it from within MonoDevelop (provided you have installed XCode), and there are lots of examples in the samples/ directory. There is even integration with the XCode interface designer.

Just recently there was a successor to MonoMac announced, which is however a commercial product: [Xamarin.Mac](http://xamarin.com/mac).